# Warning: Remote Host Identification Has Changed!

Tags: ssh

After typing the command

```
ssh -p 8101 karaf@docker-ip onos1
```

I am getting the error

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:rV+69MOdHKanIvP41a9Xspug6am7/BV7CHVjhxKYFyM.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/pranav/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/pranav/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/pranav/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [172.17.0.2]:8101
RSA host key for [172.17.0.2]:8101 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: The warning often occurs when the remote host has generated a new key pair, but  could also occur due to corruption/editing of the user's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.  What @Rinzwind suggested in [their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064701/828054) is what should be done.

Comment: There is a specific issue with karaf here. If you post this question on stackoverflow I'll try to spot it and give you specific advice.

Comment: If it's an issue with some container platform, it's not an Ubuntu problem. Voting to leave closed.

Comment: Like I said, belongs on stackoverflow.com itself.

Answer (score 8):

"Please contact your system administrator."  You need to do that. Your local ssh key does not match the remote ssh key. You need to update yours and the admin is the one to do that. By the way: what needs to be done is told in lines 10 through 12 in your  message.

If the problem is on YOUR end you can remove line THREE (and ONLY line three) in `/home/pranav/.ssh/known_hosts` and it will retry the ssh connection by verifying you.

Generally the problem should be on your end but if your key got compromised it is best to alarm the admin and have him revoke ALL ssh keys, create new keys and investigate the system on breaches.

Comment: Hmmm but I agree that the close vote has probably all the user needs :D Heck, did not scan for dupes myself and used a bit of into from there to add to mine >:-D Ill have a talk with the cv'ers in chat ;-)